# Having trouble with large numbers in Python

Tags: python, largenumber, birthday-paradox

running into problems with:

```
from pylab import *
x=arange(0,365,1)
y = []
for j in x:
    y.append(1-((math.factorial(365)/math.factorial(365-j))/(365**j)))

plot(x,y)
show()
```

Any thoughts? I'm running python 2.7

Comment: `365!` is still small enough to hold in a double precision floating point number, but generally, you want to simply that expression.  `365!/(365-j)!` is really just the product of all the numbers between `365 - j + 1` and `365`, inclusive.

Comment: @acjohnson55 -- these aren't floats we're dealing with though.

Comment: Good point. Therein lies the problem, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to this:

```
(math.factorial(365)/math.factorial(365-j))/long(365**j)
```

The problem is that `numpy` tries to convert the long to a numpy type before doing the division -- But numpy can't do that since it results in an overflow, so numpy throws an error.  If you convert to a `long` first, then the division is all done outside `numpy`.